# Tomcat 6 with SPNEGO SSO still prompts for login and password

Tags: java, tomcat, single-sign-on, spnego

I'm trying to setup a Windows Active Directory SSO for Tomcat (6), using the [SPNEGO filter](http://spnego.sourceforge.net/spnego_tomcat.html).

I've setup as in the example but I'm still prompted to enter a login and password when I try to access hello_spnego.jsp.

I'm probably missing something so here's my conf :

web.xml (relating to spnego) :

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SpnegoHttpFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoHttpFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.allow.basic</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.allow.localhost</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.allow.unsecure.basic</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.login.client.module</param-name>
        <param-value>spnego-client</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.login.server.module</param-name>
        <param-value>spnego-server</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.krb5.conf</param-name>
        <param-value>${catalina.home}\conf\krb5.conf</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.login.conf</param-name>
        <param-value>${catalina.home}\conf\login.conf</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.preauth.username</param-name>
        <param-value>aqw</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.preauth.password</param-name>
        <param-value>pass</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.prompt.ntlm</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.logger.level</param-name>
        <param-value>1</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SpnegoHttpFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

krb5.conf :

```
    [libdefaults]
default_realm = TEST.LOCAL
default_tkt_enctypes = rc4-hmac,aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96,aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96
default_tgs_enctypes = rc4-hmac,aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96,aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96
forwardable=true

[realms]
TEST.LOCAL = {
    kdc = SERVER_WITH_AD:88
    default_realm = TEST.LOCAL
}

[domain_realm]
dev.local = TEST.LOCAL
.dev.local = TEST.LOCAL
```

login.conf :

```
spnego-client {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required;
};

spnego-server {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    storeKey=true
    isInitiator=false
    useKeyTab=true
    keyTab="C:\Osys\QuartisTools\Tomcat\conf\aqw.keytab"
    ;
};
```

EDIT: Here's what I did:

- I created a user (aqw) on my server, SERVER_WITH_AD
- I set his SPN with the following command:

  setspn -A HTTP/SERVER_WITH_AD.Test.local aqw
- I created a keytab file for him with the following command:

  ktpass /out c:\aqw.keytab /mapuser aqw@Test.local /princ HTTP/TOMCAT_SERVER@Test.local /pass * /kvno 0
- I transfered the keytab file to Tomcat/conf.
- I added the login.conf and krb5.conf to Tomcat/conf.
- I edited my user's account (on AD's user interface) to accept AES 128 bits encryption.
- I added the JCE jars to my jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/security from [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) after finding the info from another question on SO.

Additional info:
- SERVER_WITH_AD runs a Windows Server 2012 (x64).
- TOMCAT_SERVER runs a Windows 7 Ultimate (x64).

EDIT 2:
As Whome suggested, I added the address to the list of the trusted sites.

At some point I've stopped seeing the username/login prompt but I'm now getting error in Tomcat (showing as a HTTP 500 error):
KrbException: Invalid argument (400) - Cannot find key of appropriate type to decrypt AP REP - AES256 CTS mode with HMAC SHA1-96
So it probably can't find my keytab.

Comment: Internet Explorer prompts you because your setup is broken.

Comment: yes, i realize that, hence the question. but broken how ? Since I'm using Tomcat and SPNEGO out of the box, it's something to do with my conf. I'll edit the question to add info.

Comment: Is hostname listed in Settings/Security/Trusted host list? Each browser has own setting for this, without it IE sends NTLM http header token instead of Kerberos ticket. https://ping.force.com/Support/PingIdentityArticle?id=kA3400000008RiECAU

Comment: It wasn't. It is now. I'm now having a different error.

Comment: Try absolute /unix/path/file.ext format in a setting file. It is fine in Java on Windows. Use it in web.xml and .conf fike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing having the "cannot find key" error, I've retread my conf files, with Whome's advice to put the file names Unix style. That and I moved them to be right next to the conf files to have the shortest paths possible. I also added a principal, [as in the server keytab testing procedure described here:](http://spnego.sourceforge.net/server_keytab.html), so that my login.conf is:

```
spnego-client {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required;
};

spnego-server {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    useKeyTab=true
    keyTab="appserver.keytab"
    principal=aqw
    storeKey=true;
};
```

This gave me a checksum error so I re-generated my keytab file.

This in turn showed a different error:
**javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No CallbackHandler available to garner authentication information from the user**

So I edited my web.xml to allow unsecure, basic, NTLM prompt and localhost. Like so:

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.prompt.ntlm</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.allow.basic</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.allow.localhost</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.allow.unsecure.basic</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

Which, weirdly, showed another exception:
**javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No CallbackHandler available to garner authentication information from the user**

I say weirdly because my understanding of it is that by allowing NTLM prompt I'm authorizing another methog for authentification.

The weirdest part is that this morning, it works. I don't know why. It still works after restarting my server. I get the "Hello user!" message with the right user. However [the HelloKeytab test class](http://spnego.sourceforge.net/client_keytab.html) doesn't work.

**EDIT: in the end, it stopped working and could not get it to work. I kept getting a checksum error. So I ended up using [Waffle](http://github.com/dblock/waffle/#waffle---windows-authentication-framework).**